# Vote counts on front page are not centered

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

On the StackOverflow front page, vote counts are not centered:

[image: not centered]

Comment: Good spot, I never noticed (granted I am using the OLD layout) :D

Answer (score 3):

It is centered *in the block it's in*, there's just *also* a 3px margin on the right-side of that block to provide spacing between the first and second column (the same is true on answers, for the second and third column).

This is by design, to have 3px spacing between the columns for more separation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be centerd to number of votes, this 3px is a seperator bettween answers?